# Datepicker with Jquery, nothing shows up on textbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to get the Jquery datepicker to work. Have tried to follow this tutorial: [Datepicker Jquery Tutorial](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default) but can't seem to get it to work.

Have used an "TextBoxFor" instead of a input field like this code:

**Code**

```
<label>Departure date</label><br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), @class = "textbox", @id = "datepicker" })
```

**Jscript code:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

I think it because i'm loading the files in a wrong way, but I'm not sure. Have loaded the files in the _Layout file:

```
 <!-- Css files -->
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The Jslib is added like this way:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Can any see what is wrong here?

**Update with html code**

```
<h3>Booking</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="col-sm-9">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>Outward route</label><br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartureRoute, Model.Routes, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })

        <br />

        <label>Departure date</label><br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), @class = "textbox", @id = "datepicker" })

        <br />

        <label>Adults:</label><br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.adults, Model.Number, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <label>Return route</label><br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnRoute, new { @class = "dropdownlist" })

        <br />

        <label>Return date</label><br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnDate, new { Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), @class = "textbox", @id = "datepicker2" })

        <br />

        <label>Childrens:</label><br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.childrens, Model.Number, new { @class = "dropdownlist" }

    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Booking infomation:</label><br />
    <button type="submit" class="button_continue">Continue</button>
</div>
}

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});  
</script>
```

Comment: did you add jQuery library( `jquery.js`)?

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML also for the textbox using razor syntax...

Comment: Now it should be correct. updated.